# Is it possible to "namespace" Rust macros?

Tags: macros, module, rust

I've been writing a lot of macros in a recent project. I was just thinking about how incredibly useful Rust's module system is for managing "namespaces", and I began to wonder:

1. Why was it decided that macros shouldn't also abide by the module system? Is it because of the general rarity of macro use? Or because of some other fundamental compilation process that restricts it?
2. Is it at all possible to "namespace" Rust macros?

This question doesn't arise from a dire need, but more from a general curiosity :-)

Comment: 'namespaced' how? as in put into modules and invoked as 'use x; x::foo!(..)'? You can already put macros in submodules import them selectively by calling 'use x;' to export macros from the module x.

Comment: @Doug yeah, I was referring to `use x; x::foo!(..)` specifically. Also, I was under the impression that the only way to use a macro was to use `#[macro_escape]` upon the module containing the macro, which would then make it available throughout the whole crate? Are you saying it's possible to not use `#[macro_escape]`, but just a regular `use x;` instead to make a macro within `x` available? edit: (sorry, accidentally clicked enter before). Thanks btw

Comment: Oo... I take it back. Looks like I've just been naively been using use x; like that assuming that's what it does. You're right, looks like once you load the module it publishes the macros globally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Macro expansion runs before "the module system", and so name resolution/searching isn't really set up at that point. Also, macros can actually create whole modules, so it's not necessarily *possible* to have the entire resolution system working. This is also part of the reason that macros are run in declaration order (the only place in Rust where this really matters), so that there's a predictable ordering for names and macros to be defined.

So, there's some technical problems. However it would be *really* nice to at least have some form of namespaced macros.

It would definitely be possible (and is essentially necessary) to have namespacing between crates, that is, if crates `a` and `b` both define `foo!`, then the following should be able to be made legal

```
#![feature(phase)]

#[phase(plugin)] extern crate a;
#[phase(plugin)] extern crate b;

fn main() {
    a::foo!();
    b::foo!();
}
```

This isn't implemented yet, but we will hopefully have something of this form eventually.

> Is it at all possible to "namespace" Rust macros?

In summary: no, except via C-namespacing: `mylib_mymodule_mymacro!()`.

Comment: "This isn't implemented yet, but we will hopefully have something of this form eventually." By this do you mean that macros would follow all the usual namespacing mechanisms of normal items, only with a different-crate restriction for invoking them (like, incidentally, Template Haskell), and `macro_export` would go away? Or something less and/or different than that?

Comment: (Or perhaps the restriction should be more fine-grained so that only macros which expand to items should be so restricted, or something like that?)

Comment: @glaebhoerl, I'm talking just about the crate-level namespacing of exported macros; having intra-crate module-level namespacing beyond just `macro_export` would be nice, but I have no idea if it's feasible.

Comment: @dbaupp agreed, would really like to see something that allowed intra-crate module-level namespacing. Rust's macros seem like quite a core part of the language compared to others, I find myself using them more and more all the time and I imagine others would also - it'd be nice to see something like this pre 1.0 to avoid the pollution before it can no longer be changed, but that's probably asking a lot (I also have no idea how feasible it would be).

Comment: Macros are feature gated and likely will be for 1.0, so things can be changed after 1.0. (Using a feature gate is opting in to an unstable feature.)

Comment: Is that also the case for merely invoking macros such as `println!`? Or, in a hypothetical future world with namespaced macros, would those just be added to the prelude to retain compatibility?

Comment: @glaebhoerl, the built-in macros are not feature gated, and should have [stability attributes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/rustdoc.html#stability), to allow fine-grained per-macro stabilisation. (Any stable ones would be added to the prelude, I guess.) At the moment, stability attributes are not supported on macros, but hopefully in future.

Comment: ([#15728](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15728) covers stability & macros.)

Comment: This answer needs an update: does Rust still not have namespaced macros, as of 2021?

Comment: *"This isn't implemented yet, but we will hopefully have something of this form eventually."* Has this changed since 2014? When reading new code, it is frustrating to see a macro in a file that has a half dozen or more `use` statements and have no idea where the macro comes from.

Comment: I believe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files#31749071 which has an updated answer.