# How to Rust macro in another project?

Tags: rust

Hi is it possible to use a custom declarative macro across multiple projects? If yes, how?

The project tree structure looks like this:
(the macro is defined in proj1)

```
.
├── proj1
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── proj2
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── proj3
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── main.rs
```

Comment: Yes, you can use path dependencies https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies

Comment: @Zeppi Thx for ur fast answer. Could you make an explicit example on how to use it in my project structure?

Answer (score 0):

`proj1` would need to be a hybrid bin/lib crate for you to be able to use a macro from it. This would mean moving your macro to a `proj1/src/lib.rs`. However, I suggest you move common functionality to a different crate, let's call it `lib1`. The rest has already been described [in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files), so here is a quick demo only:

```sh
cargo new --lib lib1
cargo new proj2
echo 'lib1 = { path = "../lib1" }' >>proj2/Cargo.toml
echo '#[macro_export] macro_rules! mahcro { () => { println!("Hello macro.") } }' >lib1/src/lib.rs
echo 'use lib1::mahcro; fn main() { mahcro!() }' >proj2/src/main.rs
cargo run --manifest-path proj2/Cargo.toml
```

By the way, workspaces are really useful in this kind of setup, I recommend you read up on them.