# How to export function and macro with the same name?

Tags: rust, module, rust-macros

Is it possible to export a function and a macro with the same name from a module?

Example `lib.rs`

```rust
mod log;

fn foo() {
    log::info!("");
    log::info("");
}
```

In `log.rs`:

- Using `pub(crate) use info;` conflicts with `pub fn info() { .. }`
- Using `#[macro_export]` and `#[macro_use]` doesn't allow namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros and functions belong to different [namespaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/names/namespaces.html) so two with the same name should happily coexist. This compiles ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=646ce68df0120067de22570f57a95c06)):

```
macro_rules! info {
    ($v:expr) => {}
}

fn info(v: &str) { }
```

However, trouble seems to arise when when trying to make them public from within a module. Exporting the macro as shown in [How do I use a macro across module files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files) seems to conflict somehow with the function declaration ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fca103097ad41fd5dee5ac89d33b3c7)):

```
mod log {
    macro_rules! info {
        ($v:expr) => {}
    }
    
    pub(crate) use info;
    
    pub fn info(v: &str) { }
}
```

```
error[E0255]: the name `info` is defined multiple times
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
6 |     pub(crate) use info;
  |                    ---- previous import of the value `info` here
7 |     
8 |     pub fn info(v: &str) { }
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `info` redefined here
  |
  = note: `info` must be defined only once in the value namespace of this module
help: you can use `as` to change the binding name of the import
  |
6 |     pub(crate) use info as other_info;
  |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I do not know if this is a bug or intended behavior. Either way it is confusing.

---

A workaround that I found was to declare the function in a separate module and then re-export it by wildcard in the original module ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=467b752fa096a418f618d5c026025adc)):

```
mod log {
    mod imp {
        pub fn info(v: &str) { }
    }
    
    pub use imp::*;
    
    macro_rules! info {
        ($v:expr) => { }
    }
    
    pub(crate) use info;
}
```

You can do it the other way (i.e. putting the macro in a separate module) but the compiler strangely yields a warning that it didn't re-export anything even when it did ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9923b3244c93469e16029432d7901c8)).