# How should I use `macro_export` for a custom module

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have the following structure:

[image]

Inside `queues.rs` I have a `#[macro_export]`,

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! queue {...}
```

but I am not sure how to import it in `lib.rs`.

What I have looks like this:

```
use crate::utils::queues::*;

// use it here
let mut service_queue: Queue<isize> = queue![];
```

This throws an error

```
error: cannot find macro `queue` in this scope
  --> src/broker.rs:54:51
   |
54 |             let mut service_queue: Queue<isize> = queue![];
   |                                                   ^^^^^
   |
   = note: consider importing this macro:
           crate::queue
   = help: have you added the `#[macro_use]` on the module/import?
```

What is the correct way to type `#[macro_use]` here, and import my custom macros from `utils`?

Comment: It's hard to say without source code, but putting `#[macro_use]` on the `mod queues` item should do it. You can't use `extern crate` here because `queues` is a module; not a crate.

Comment: @Smitop I hopefully made the question clearer now, let me know if it still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `queue!` macro from `lib.rs` using the [`#[macro_use]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#the-macro_use-attribute) attribute ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=adf3465ad314b596ffebba6e1e4ae016)):

```
#[macro_use]
mod utils {
    #[macro_use]
    mod queues {
        macro_rules! queue {
            () => { vec![] };
        }
    }
}

pub fn foo() {
    let _service_queue: Vec<isize> = queue![];
}
```

In your existing code you are using `#[macro_export]` which means it is [declared in the crate root scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#path-based-scope) and not in the `utils::queues` module.  In your error message you can see the compile is suggesting to `consider importing this macro: crate::queue`.

To access it in this case ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51264f7088cdd56ecd66c203294d1cc7)):

```
mod utils {
    mod queues {
        #[macro_export]
        macro_rules! queue {
            () => { vec![] };
        }
    }
}

pub fn foo() {
    let _service_queue: Vec<isize> = queue![];
}
```

Note that in either case the `use crate::utils::queues::*;` statement does not help, in fact you'll get an `unused_imports` warning (unless you happen to have other items declared in that module).

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files) trick ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bbb5877b99961257fa74631d2f43550a)):

```
pub mod utils {
    pub mod queues {
        macro_rules! queue {
            () => { vec![] };
        }
        pub(crate) use queue;
    }
}

pub fn foo() {
    let _service_queue: Vec<isize> = crate::utils::queues::queue![];
}
```

Aside: if you plan to use the macro in other crates and you wish to retain the module hierarchy (i.e. access from `my_crate::utils::queues::queue!` from `my_other_crate`) there is a (convoluted) way to do that.

Comment: I understand your last suggestion. I have no idea what the first two are though. Are you redefining my `queues` macro inside `lib.rs`? It's already created inside `utils::queues` I just want to import it somehow and use it.

Comment: @dearn44 no, the macro is still defined in the `utils::queues` module and imported in the root module, I just used Rust syntax for defining nested modules in a single source file (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html)) rather than separate files.  The approaches shown will work if you spit the modules into separate files, give it a try.

Comment: I seen what you mean now.