# How do I import a macro from the tests directory?

Tags: rust

I created a macro and 'exported' it in 'lib.rs' file like this:

```rust
pub mod utils {
  macro_rules! my_macro {
    () => {};
  }
  
  pub(crate) use my_macro;

}
```

The code above is working fine and I can use `my_macro` in all modules,
But the problem is I can't use (import) it in 'tests' directory to test it. like so:

```rust
use my_crate::utils::my_macro;
```

The compiler gives me an error: 'macro `my_macro` is private'. So what should I do?

Comment: what is you project file structure? is your `tests` directory in the crate root? if not, replacing `pub(crate)` with `pub` may fix it

Comment: @Jeremy Meadows tests directory is next to 'src' directory. replacing `pub(crate)` with pub gives me another error: 'my_macro is only public within the crate, and cannot be re-exported outside
'

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files The key thing here is that the tests in the "tests" directory are not in the same crate as the library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a macro across module files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [#macro_export] to export the macro from one crate to another. Like this.

```
#[macro_export]
pub mod utils {
  macro_rules! my_macro {
    () => {};
  }  
  pub(crate) use my_macro;
}
```