# Extracting embedded-hal pin definitions into a separate file

Tags: rust, embedded, coding-style

I would like to make my project's pin layout configurable and extract all pin number definitions into a separate module.

I can't erase all pins because I still want to take advantage of embedded-hal's automatic pin checking e.g. when setting SPI/timer pins.

So far I've come up with:

```rust
# in hardware_config.rs
 
pub struct AllGpio {
    pub a: hal::gpio::gpioa::Parts,
    pub b: hal::gpio::gpiob::Parts,
    pub c: hal::gpio::gpioc::Parts,
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! display_rst_pin {
    ($gpio:ident) => {
        $gpio.a.pa11
    };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! display_sclk_pin {
    ($gpio:ident) => {
        $gpio.a.pa5
    };
}

<...more>
```

```rust
# in actual code

let gpio = AllGpio {
    a: dp.GPIOA.split(),
    b: dp.GPIOB.split(),
    c: dp.GPIOC.split(),
};

let mut rst_pin = hw::display_rst_pin!(gpio).into_push_pull_output();
let mut sclk_pin = hw::display_sclk_pin!(gpio).into_alternate();

<...more>
```

However the macro definitions are very verbose here, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is, please clarify. Your title asks how to move them to another file, and your question in the text asks for a general cleaner way. Which one is it? If the first one, it might be a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731243/how-do-i-use-a-macro-across-module-files

Comment: I was trying to avoid falling into the XY problem here - my original issue is that I want to have one place where the entire pinout configuration is defined, but the solution I came up (macros) with is too verbose.

Comment: *"too verbose"* - to what standard? What would be compact enough in your opinion?
One could pack all of the definitions into a single macro. Or define a macro that generates the macros. But again, the metric of what 'cleaner' means is somewhat unclear, pushing this entire question into opinion-based territory.

Comment: That's why I tagged it coding-style. Ideally, there'd be some compile-type attribute substitution like `gpioa.[const rst_pin_name].into_output()` but I know that doesn't exist, hence the question

Comment: You might want to read the mouse-over text of the `coding-style` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using this meta-macro:

```rust
pub struct AllGpio {
    pub a: hal::gpio::gpioa::Parts,
    pub b: hal::gpio::gpiob::Parts,
    pub c: hal::gpio::gpioc::Parts,
}

#[rustfmt::skip]
macro_rules! pin_macro {
    ($d:tt $name:ident, $gpio:ident, $pin:ident) => {
        #[macro_export]
        macro_rules! $name {
            ($d gpio:ident) => {
                $d gpio. $gpio . $pin
            };
        }

        pub use $name;
    };
}

pin_macro!($ display_dc_pin, a, pa8);
pin_macro!($ display_rst_pin, a, pa10);
pin_macro!($ display_sclk_pin, a, pa5);
pin_macro!($ display_miso_pin, a, pa6);

// ----

let mut dc_pin = hw::display_dc_pin!(gpio).into_push_pull_output();
let mut rst_pin = hw::display_rst_pin!(gpio).into_push_pull_output();
```